# Does Snowflake Data Sharing add any real security?

Tags: databases, cloud-computing, security-theater

[Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/) is a cloud database like [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) or [Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/). Unlike them, however, it markets a ["Secure Data Sharing"](https://www.snowflake.com/use-cases/modern-data-sharing/) feature.

They go to some effort (including a full ["Data Sharing for Dummies"](https://resources.snowflake.com/data-sharing/data-sharing-for-dummies%22) book) to position this as something unique. In terms of clearly defining who has access to what in a user-friendly way, maybe they are correct.

But does this add any extra security above simply [sharing a BigQuery dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls) or [creating a read-only Redshift user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html)?